# PostGIS and GDAL: ST_AsGDALRaster doesn't work

Tags: postgresql, gis, postgis, gdal, wms

I installed, on Ubuntu 16.04, PostgreSQL 10 and PostGIS 2.4. I also installed GDAL 2.2.

I created my database and I enabled GDAL RASTER with following commands:

```
ALTER DATABASE gisdb SET postgis.gdal_datapath = '/usr/share/gdal/2.2';
ALTER DATABASE gisdb SET postgis.gdal_enabled_drivers TO 'ENABLE_ALL';
ALTER DATABASE gisdb SET postgis.postgis.enable_outdb_rasters TO true;
```

If I use ST_GDALRaster for create output in WMS format, with following command:

```
select ST_AsGDALRaster(rast,'WMS') from my_raster
```

Postgresql generates the error:

> ERROR:  rt_raster_to_gdal: Could not create the output GDAL dataset

Moreover if I get installed GDAL drivers with:

```
select * from postgis_full_version();
```

PostgreSQL shows:

[image]

If I run `SELECT postgis_full_version();`

Postgresql says that installed GDAL version is the 1.11.3 not 2.2

[image]

Any idea?

Comment: I think your PostGis GDAL version should match your GDAL data path version...

Comment: I will try to change the data path to 1.11.3 data folder

Comment: I changed the data path to 1.11.3 data folder but it doesn't work

Comment: Have you seen this ? https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/ticket/4130